# Overlapping uibuttons added programmatically

Tags: ios

I have an array of Plus buttons and another array of Minus buttons added programatically. Minus buttons lies exactly under Plus buttons. Code is:

```
    int x=0;
    for (int t=0;t<=14;t++){
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressedPlus:)                forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
     button.tag = t;
    [button setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     button.frame = CGRectMake(270, x+10, 13, 13);
    [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed: 10.0/255.0f green:100.0/255.0f   blue:150.0/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
     button.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Plus"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [segmentedView1 addSubview:button];
    [self.view addSubview:segmentedView1];
    x+=20;

    }



    int x1=0;
    for (int t1=0;t1<=14;t1++){
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressedMinus:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        button.tag = t1;
        [button setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(270, x1+10, 13, 13);
        [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed: 10.0/255.0f green:100.0/255.0f blue:150.0/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Minus"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [segmentedView1 addSubview:button];
        [self.view addSubview:segmentedView1];
        x1+=20;
    }
```

Now my task is..when a plus button is pressed once, the minus button under it should be visible and once the minus button is pressed, plus button should be visible again. 
How to do it?

Comment: Don't use two buttons, just change the senders title when it is pressed

Comment: I agree with @JayMorgan. You should add single buttons for both **plus** and **minus**. In the target method, use an **if** to differentiate which operation should be performed, and then toggle the title of the button.

Comment: as u said, iam using only one button whose default image is plus. and once it is clicked the image changes to minus. till here is fine. and once minus button is pressed, i want to get back the image to plus and repeat the same action of plus button. how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Button overlaps because in both the cases your x = 0;
You can do this in a single for loop.

```
   int x=0;
        for (int t=0;t<=14;t++){
    //plus button
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressedPlus:)                forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
         button.tag = t;
        [button setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         button.frame = CGRectMake(270, x+10, 13, 13);
        [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed: 10.0/255.0f green:100.0/255.0f   blue:150.0/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
         button.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Plus"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [segmentedView1 addSubview:button];
        [self.view addSubview:segmentedView1];
        x+=20;

    // minus button 
     UIButton *buttonM = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [buttonM addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressedMinus:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        buttonM.tag = t1+1000;
        [buttonM setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        buttonM.frame = CGRectMake(270, x+10, 13, 13);
        [buttonM setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed: 10.0/255.0f green:100.0/255.0f blue:150.0/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
        buttonM.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
        [buttonM setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Minus"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [segmentedView1 addSubview:buttonM];
        [self.view addSubview:segmentedView1];
        x+=20;
        }

//
-(void)buttonPressedPlus:(id)sender{
// in this show minus button please also take care of tag ex:-1000
// in this hide plus button please also take care of tag ex:-0.
}
-(void)buttonPressedMinus:(id)sender{
// in this hide minus button please also take care of tag
// in this show plus button please also take care of tag.
}
```

Comment: in buttonPressedMinus method, hiding the minus button once it is clicked is fine..but how to make the plus button reappear?

Comment: can u help me how to show and hide buttons here as i dont have any sender in the methods mentioned by u